# Using Scalatra's halt() in a function

Tags: java, web-services, scala, servlets, scalatra

My Scalatra web service has a lot of GET routes. Everyone of them needs nearly identical code for caching and for authentication/authorization, and repetitive code is stupid.

I want to refactor that code with the help of implicit parameters into e.g. a function `cached` that automatically checks if a given ETag is still correct/ressource was not modified since.

Setting `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` / `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`as implicit parameters was pretty easy, but now I want to short circuit a given E304-case directly from that subfunction. Normally, you'd use Scalatra's `halt()`. As far as I understand, a given Servlet gets those by inheritance. Therefore I need to give my function my servlet as a parameter (Java developers love `this`).

Is this a solid strategy (from the POV of good refactoring)? Is there maybe a more elegant way to get access to that single member `halt()`?